# How to quit on a python quiz

Tags: python, python-requests

This is a basic math quiz that I have to make but I have yet to figure out how to allow the play to exit. I have made it so that whenever you press -1, you exit. It works but only on every third question asked so I wish to change that.

I'm only a student starting python so please give out any suggestions and explain what I have done wrong. If you have any ideas for improvement, then I request you to share it if possible.

```
import random

print ('Welcome to my quiz. Enter the correct answer for the given math equation.')

print ('Enter -1 to quit')

Score = 0
UserInput = 0
CorrectAnswer = 0
CorrectAnswer2 = 0
CorrectAnswer3 = 0
IncorrectAnswer = 0
num1 = 0
num2 = 0
num3 = 0
num4 = 0
num5 = 0
num6 = 0
ans = 0

while ans != -1:
    print ('\n')
    num1 = random.randint (1,12)
    num2 = random.randint (1,12)
    num3 = random.randint (1,25)
    num4 = random.randint (1,25)
    num5 = random.randint (50,100)
    num6 = random.randint (1,25)
    CorrectAnswer = num1 * num2
    CorrectAnswer2 = num3 + num4
    CorrectAnswer3 = num5 - num6



    print ('What is ', num1, ' x ', num2, '?')
    ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
    if ans == CorrectAnswer:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer)
        Score = Score -1

    print ('What is ', num3, ' + ', num4, '?' )
    ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
    if ans == CorrectAnswer2:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer2)
        Score = Score -1

    print ('What is ', num5, ' - ', num6, '?' )
    ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
    if ans == CorrectAnswer3:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer3)
        Score = Score - 1

    if ans == -1:



print ('\n')
print ('Well done, Your final score is: ', Score)
```

Comment: Few things to point out, while ans!=-1 won't work as it will only be "active" at the point where your exit clause is. It needs to be a case for all your questions. Also, I'd suggest using something other than -1 as it is possible for the value to be -1 mathematically. You might want to use a function as well which would be much cleaner. Finally, as a programmer you should consider what happens if the user enters an invalid input. For example in your case, something that cannot be used by int(input) #hint its a string.

Comment: Since I'm new to python, my teacher suggested using -1 and so I did. Thank you for telling me about the exit clause as I hadn't thought of that/

Comment: If you need a solution do drop another message and I'll post one up. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
import random

print ('Welcome to my quiz. Enter the correct answer for the given math equation.')

print ('Enter -1 to quit')

Score = 0
UserInput = 0
CorrectAnswer = 0
CorrectAnswer2 = 0
CorrectAnswer3 = 0
IncorrectAnswer = 0
num1 = 0
num2 = 0
num3 = 0
num4 = 0
num5 = 0
num6 = 0
ans = 0


print('\n')
num1 = random.randint (1,12)
num2 = random.randint (1,12)
num3 = random.randint (1,25)
num4 = random.randint (1,25)
num5 = random.randint (50,100)
num6 = random.randint (1,25)
CorrectAnswer = num1 * num2
CorrectAnswer2 = num3 + num4
CorrectAnswer3 = num5 - num6


print ('What is ', num1, ' x ', num2, '?')
ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
if ans != -1:
    if ans == CorrectAnswer:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer)
        Score = Score -1

    print ('What is ', num3, ' + ', num4, '?' )
    ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
    if ans == CorrectAnswer2:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer2)
        Score = Score -1

    print ('What is ', num5, ' - ', num6, '?' )
    ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
    if ans == CorrectAnswer3:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer3)
        Score = Score - 1
else:
    pass


print('\n')
print ('Well done, Your final score is: ', Score)
```

Comment: Are you sure "whenever you press -1, you exit"? It seems like you test `-1` only in first question.

Comment: yes it will try it, the code will not procede if '-1' is entered

Comment: Hmmm. I've just checked it. I input `18` (it asked me about 6x3), then `-1` and got incorrect instead of break quiz.

Answer (score 1):

I have reduced the number of variables using lists. I also added f flags to strings so as not to abuse concatenation. And in general, I slightly improved your code (visually) :)

```
import random
import sys
import time

print ('Welcome to my quiz. Enter the correct answer for the given math equation.')
print ('Enter -1 to quit \n')

Score = 0
ans = None

num = [random.randint(1,12) for i in range(6)]
num[4] = random.randint(50,100)

CorrectAnswers = [
    num[0] * num[1],
    num[2] + num[3],
    num[4] - num[5]]

while True:


    print (f'What is {num[0]} x {num[1]}?')
    ans = int(input('Answer: '))

    if ans == CorrectAnswers[0]:
        print ('Correct!')
        Score += 1
    elif ans == -1:
        break
    else:
        print (f'Incorrect \n The correct answer is: {CorrectAnswers[0]}')
        Score -= 1



    print (f'What is {num[2]} + {num[3]}?' )
    ans = int (input('Answer: '))

    if ans == CorrectAnswers[1]:
        print ('Correct!')
        Score += 1
    elif ans == -1:
        break
    else:
        print (f'Incorrect \n The correct answer is: {CorrectAnswers[1]}')
        Score -= 1


    print (f'What is {num[4]} - {num[5]}?' )
    ans = int(input('Answer: '))

    if ans == CorrectAnswers[2]:
        print ('Correct!')
        Score += 1
    elif ans == -1:
        break
    else:
        print (f'Incorrect \n The correct answer is:  {CorrectAnswers[2]}')
        Score -= 1


print (f'\n Well done, Your final score is: {Score}')
time.sleep(2)
sys.exit()
```

Regarding the task. There are many ways to exit in Python, but I still chose sys.exit().
If you want to make this code perfect, read about OOP in Python and also check out PEP8, the python language code style.

OOP: https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Code style: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way IMO.

I've just added `if ans == 1: break` after each `input`.

```py
import random

print ('Welcome to my quiz. Enter the correct answer for the given math equation.')

print ('Enter -1 to quit')

Score = 0

while True:
    print ('\n')
    num1 = random.randint (1,12)
    num2 = random.randint (1,12)
    num3 = random.randint (1,25)
    num4 = random.randint (1,25)
    num5 = random.randint (50,100)
    num6 = random.randint (1,25)
    CorrectAnswer = num1 * num2
    CorrectAnswer2 = num3 + num4
    CorrectAnswer3 = num5 - num6

    print ('What is ', num1, ' x ', num2, '?')
    ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
    if ans == -1:
        break
    if ans == CorrectAnswer:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer)
        Score = Score -1

    print ('What is ', num3, ' + ', num4, '?' )
    ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
    if ans == -1:
        break
    if ans == CorrectAnswer2:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer2)
        Score = Score -1

    print ('What is ', num5, ' - ', num6, '?' )
    ans = int (input ('Answer: '))
    if ans == -1:
        break
    if ans == CorrectAnswer3:
        print ('Correct! ')
        Score = Score + 1
    else:
        print ('Incorrect')
        print ('The correct answer is: ', CorrectAnswer3)
        Score = Score - 1

print ('\n')
print ('Well done, Your final score is: ', Score)
```

BTW. Some tips.

You don't need to initialize variables on the top if you do it later (by assigning new value).

Python variables starts from lower case typically (classes from upper case).

You can increment and decrement in shorter way `x += 1`

It's nice if arguments are separated by space, eg. `random.randint(1, 12)`

Space after function (like `input` or `print` in Python 3) is not necessary.

You can join new line and strings, ex. `print('\nWell done, Your final score is:', Score)` BTW. arguments in `print` are separated by space by default.

For Python 3.6+ you can use format-string, it is easier (see `f` before `'`):
`print(f'\nWell done, Your final score is: {Score}')` or
`print(f'What is {num3} + {num4}?')`

Comment: Thank you. 
This is my first creating a python code and this helped a lot.